# Sums like $1+2+...=-1/12$ which give $1/3$? [Not a duplicate]

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation, analytic-continuation

This isn't a duplicate: I am looking for a sum or sums which are similar to $1+2+3+\cdots=-\frac{1}{12}$ but which have an answer (via analytic continuation) of $\pm \frac{1}{3}$ rather than $-\frac{1}{12}$. By similar I mean it is an infinite series of whole numbers.

Comment: multiply the present series by 4?

Comment: See this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190135/can-we-use-analytic-continuation-to-obtain-sum-n-1-infty-n-b-b-neq-fra/2190233#2190233) the result can be anything

Answer (score 2):

In a comment to my answer :  [Is $1+2+3+4+\cdots=-\frac{1}{12}$ the unique ''value'' of this series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170792/is-1234-cdots-frac112-the-unique-value-of-this-series) ,
 Sangchul Lee  reported a result from [physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233473/why-does-analytic-continuation-as-a-regularization-work-at-all) that gives:

$$
\lim_{s\to 0^+}\left[\mbox{analitic continuation of}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(n+\alpha)^s} \right]=\frac{\alpha^2}{2}-\frac{1}{12}
$$

I've not verified thi result (but  a proof is here: [Can we use analytic continuation to obtain $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = b, b\neq -\frac{1}{12}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190135/can-we-use-analytic-continuation-to-obtain-sum-n-1-infty-n-b-b-neq-fra/2190233#2190233)) and you can find $\alpha$ such that the limits becomes $ \frac{1}{3}$, but the series is **not** a series of integer numbers. So, I suspect that we cannot find such a series of whole numbers.