# Where have divergent infinite sums been successfully substituted for their corresponding Riemann Zeta results? (i.e $1+2+3\dots=-1/12$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

[In this numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Oazb7IWzbA) Professor Frenkel states that divergent infinite sums have been substituted for their "finite parts" (i.e $-1/12$ for $1+2+3+\dots$) and yielded correct answers (that have then been justified in other ways). What are some examples of this?

Comment: Maybe this is better to ask in physics.se ?

Comment: You can see some reference here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170792/is-1234-cdots-frac112-the-unique-value-of-this-series